# How to set session value to empty string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, global-asax

How to set Session value to empty("") string in Global.asax page event when session start?
Can any please help me.

Answer (score 6):

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["valueKey"] = String.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

Add `Session_Start` to `global.asax` and set the variable to `string.Empty`.

#### Sample

```
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Session["Key"] = string.Empty;
 }
```

#### More Information

- [Example Using Session_Start in Global.asax](http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/example-using-session_start-in-global-asax/)
- [MSDN - Global.asax File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - String.Empty Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx)
- [MSDN - ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session["myvar"] = string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in global.asax:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session.Add("myKeyString",string.Empty);
}
```